# Suitable soil mix for plant succulent in glass bowl?

Tags: succulents

I want to plant some succulent in a glass bowl because it is beautiful and easy to carry but their is no hole. What is the suitable mix for succulent living in glass bowl?

Answer (score 2):

Oh dear - most plants require drainage, and don't do too well without it unless they have a requirement for very moist air and roots, as in, for instance,  terrarium plants. Succulents in particular need very good, sharp drainage, so I wouldn't recommend a succulent for planting in this glass bowl at all. However, if you insist on trying, put a layer of horticultural grit in the bottom, a good inch, preferably 2 or 3, then a sharp mix of compost on top and plant into that, but I don't hold out much hope of the plant's survival without succumbing to fungal infection.

Comment: Yes, it is very beautiful. That's why gardeners and flowers shops put hem in it. You have to know that these plants are destined to die. Just like cut flowers in water. If you know it, and if you are willing to let die your plants and replace them every time, then you can use these containers.